# Skip, Take to Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a model "MainCategory".
 How can I take 3 categories only from my mainCategory?

```
var mainCategory = _context.MainCategories
  .Include(c => c.Categories)
  .Skip(0)
  .Take(3)
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Although this is seemingly a simple question, i am left guessing at what you actually want, please be more specific

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I'm creating a page where I can browse the list of all main categories. Each main category includes any more categories. I want each main category display just 3 categories, and not more. How can I do it?

Comment: I think Op tries to achieve Include Filter. EfCore currently does not support that out of the box.

Comment: so you want to select 3 `Categories` that are related to a `MainCategory`?

Answer (score 1):

EfCore does not support that out of the box. However, the below can be used as a workaround in some specific cases

```
var mainCategory = _context.MainCategories
  .Select(c => new
    {
        c,
        Categories= c.Categories.OrderBy(x => x.CategoryID)
  .Skip((PageSize * PageNumber) - PageSize)
  .Take(PageSize)
    })
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

P.S: DbContext can't track the object anymore. This is the downside of this approach